# Do we need a [home]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, clean-up

[home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home) doesn't have a wiki, but it does have a very specific excerpt,

> Home normally refers to: a web site, a starting folder or a button which brings the user back to the main page.

Which, in my opinion, is a rather generic and unclear description, "...*normally* refers to...". Tags should be specific and discrete, not clouded in vague "normally"s and referring to multiple "unconnected" subjects/fields (how does a website have any relation to a starting folder?).

Therefore, I propose we demolish our [home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home), pick up the salvageable rubble and recycle it (retag/clean up). What do you say?

The stats,

- 7% of questions are closed,
- 57% have a score of 0 or less,
- ~23 questions per week,
- 269 questions tagged,
- 9 followers.

**Update:**
All questions have been retagged.

Comment: Home is most used with android http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=home not sure why...

Comment: @rene And only 5 are actually tagged with folder. Makes even more sense to clean up the tag.

Comment: Yeah, that tag is not helping in any sensible way...

Comment: “how does a website have any relation to a starting folder?”—websites use URIs which use the folder hierarchy concept, with `/` being the “starting folder”. In the case of a traditional website, this even directly maps onto a folder on the server ;-).

Comment: I've retagged every question from [home], now there is only 1 question that cannot be edited (it was merged). Should we burninate?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would agree that the tag is largely useless.

If it is removed now there are a number of questions though that will end up with a single (and sometimes meaningless) tag. The list of questions isn't huge, I would suggest that you pre-process the list and do a general clean up before requesting a final burnination.

Comment: Ok, so "fix up" and retag the posts, then request burnination, right?

Comment: @Sam Yeah, there are few tags that can be outright burninated without consequence, it's best to do some prep work first then blast it once you're sure everything is squared away.

Comment: In the mean time I've removed the burnination tag from your question as it's currently just a discussion. When you're set to go put in another burnination request/question, link to this one as a reference, and use the tag.

Comment: Alright, will do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be less hassle to just "clean-up" the posts *while* burninating? Anyway, I always thought burninating a tag meant fixup the posts while removing said tag, right?

Comment: @Sam Not necessarily. Frequently the messy state of a tag can trigger a burnination request, once a pre-cleanup is done it can then be confirmed for sure whether the tag is junk or not. I'm a big fan of requesters doing their homework before requesting the burnination, like [Soner did here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262962/109702). You'd be surprised how many requests simply state the reason as "sounds unnecessary" or something equally unconvincing.

Comment: Right I see, I'll carry on tidying up then...

Comment: I've retagged every question from [home], now there is only 1 question that cannot be edited (it was merged). Should we burninate?

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Thanks to Sam for pointing out that there is a android-homebutton tag already. So no need for a home tag for Android.

---

Android has a concept of "home".
Most Android devices (going back to at least Android 1.5) have a home button.

When you press it, you are usually sent to a place where some app icons and widgets live, and this place is actually sometimes called "home" too.

The same concept might or might not exist on other operating systems.
Example of question that could benefit from this tag: [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)

That being said I agree that a tag with this meaning should have a different name, indeed, because just "home" is ambiguous.

Comment: Well there is a [`android-homebutton`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-homebutton) tag.

Comment: Another meaning: the `/home` folder in a linux system...

Comment: Windows phone has the same concept

Answer (score 4):

On each question, the [home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home) tag should be replaced with one of these:

- [android-homebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-homebutton) for Android home button questions
- [android-launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-launcher) for Android home screen app questions
- [home-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home-directory) for `/home` questions
- [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpage) for home page questions
- [windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) for Windows phone home questions (or create a new [windows-phone-homebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-homebutton) tag?)
- *Edit to add more*