# Burninate the [tape] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I'm not sure we should have a [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) tag:

- It has only 5 followers ✔
- There is no tag wiki ✔
- Highest voted question score is 3  ✔
- There are only 32 tagged questions at the moment ✔
- There is only [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15707313/447156) where [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) is [the *only* tag and this question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197149/burninate-helper?TagName=tape) points to [Dell PowerVault TL2000 physical library](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=Dell%20PowerVault%20TL2000) ✔
- The tag by itself is kind of, ehm.. broad. ✔

Also

- Can you be a [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) expert? *Well*, kind of.. but tape programming? I don't know actually. **X**
- Does [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) adds anything valuable to the question? In SO, no. (maybe in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/))
- Does a question directly relate to [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) ever? *Well*, not in SO probably..

%99 of questions of tagged [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) about physical devices (There is a one question points to *Tape drives* under the Device Manager but still shouldn't tagged with [tape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tape) IMO). I strongly feel this tag doesn't fit a website that focuses on a programming.

Should we burninate this tag?

Comment: Nice! This could be a poster-child question for how to request a burnination :)

Comment: 24 of these questions already contain "tape" in the title... Therefore the tag is redundant.

Comment: What???  How would I tag all my questions about DC300 tape drives??

Comment: I don't see the problem with the tag. Anyone wanting to write a program that does anything with a tape drive will have to take into account the various constraints tape imposes and choose algorithms accordingly.

Comment: A few questions tagged with "tape" are refering to [this android library](https://github.com/square/tape) so they should be switched over to the existing [square-tape].

Comment: @dfeuer, my mind just exploded.

Comment: Knuth wrote quite a lot about sorting on tapes etc.

Comment: @paqogomez - I'm a bit confused... Why did dfeuer's comment cause your mind to explode? Is it really that baffling that someone does, in fact, have to write software specific to tape devices? Someone has to write drivers and firmware for any type of device and such questions are perfectly on topic for SO, as would be questions related to developing backup utilities that specifically deal with tape backup devices. While I don't doubt that many of the questions that were tagged as 'tape' were off-topic, it's not inconceivable that a legitimate one could come up.

Comment: I actually had a company contact me via careers 2.0 for a tape device firmware development position just last year.

Comment: Suggested title: `Can we [tape] over this tag?`