# What is the policy for tag creation and removal?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I was just acting as reviewer on Stack Overflow, and was reviewing the wiki entry for a new tag [qfileinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qfileinfo). This relates to a single class in the Qt5 abstraction within the Stack Overflow [qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt5). This tag seems to have have been automatically created because one user has asked a couple of Qs with this invented tag. Some user then proposes the tag content, which needs reviewing and this is where I come in.

My view is that this is an excessive level of tag granulation. But was is the policy on "significance" which merits the creation of tags and how are tags which fail that policy policed and removed?

My only sensible option here seems to be to skip the edit and move on. There is no option to vote for "this tag shouldn't have been created in the first place".

Comment: There is a tag for [nullreferenceexception], a single class.  There are several [android] tags related to single classes, like [android-activity] and [android-intent].  Several tags exist for *individual methods.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am a also a WP editor and it has a [WP:Notability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability) policy to guide you and a process for flagging and sentencing articles that aren't notable. What I am asking is: does such a concept operate on SO? What you are saying is that there already precedents, but my response would be that in the case of Android there are a huge no of Qs and ditto `[android-activity]` so these are notable tags.  This one isn't.

Comment: AFAIK notability isn't one of our concerns.  It's still a valid tag, even if you've never personally heard of the library before, or its classes.  I think it's fair to say that tags are not really the same thing as Wikipedia categories, although they do bear a resemblance.  I'm pretty sure you have a way to remove an entire category on Wikipedia if you need to; here, we must remove tags individually from every question, a rather onerous process.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thanks Robert.  But "AFAIK" is my point in a way.  You've got a rep of 100K and can't point me to where the policy "one tag is valid" is in a help or FAQ.   (I did try looking).  I just answer Qs on SO on a couple of niche subjects so my SO rep is only 5.5 K :-(

Comment: I don't think there is a policy, to be honest.  There are [some](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) [guiding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)  [principles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262962/burninate-the-tape-tag), but they boil down to "avoid tags that are meaningless."

Comment: But as to your last point, then should there be some approval process and guidelines to prevent spurious tags being created in the first place? What would happen if I started post Qs tagged `[MS is crap]` (or iOS or whatever my favourite poison view was)?

Comment: Those get quickly edited.

Comment: I found that guiding principles post.  But as to your assertion that they get quickly edited, I could pick more subtle -- yet clearly non-notable examples (and still defamatory for example) and ask the Q on a niche tag like one I answer Qs on: `[opcache]`  How would they get spotted let alone quickly edited.

Comment: I've raised the issue.  It has no traction, so let's leave it there :-)

Comment: There have been multiple discussions, but I don't remember that any lead to a full rule. For example, [Should tags be created for functions of APIs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis/360290#360290)