# A [logical] discussion finally ends

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Following the format of [the burnination request for [tape]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262962/4015623), I don't think that we need the [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) tag (369 questions):

- It has only 3 followers ✔
- There is no tag wiki ✔
- There is only 1 question where [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) is the *only* tag, and that is [Random Number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10143163/359284) ✔
- The tag is, by itself, very broad ✔

Also

- Can you be a [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) expert? *Well*, not really. Basically everything you do in programming is (or should be) in some way logical.
- Does [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) add anything valuable to the question? Not at all.
- Does a question directly relate to [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) ever? Not really, because, again, almost everything we do is logical.

We already have a [logical-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-operators) tag, along with a [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag. Currently, most of the questions tagged with [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) have to do either with logical operators, or with some sort of logical structure, such as [proper use of an if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429385/what-should-be-passed-into-if-to-print-hello-world) or [why "one" < 2 is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005295/why-is-one-2-false-in-r). I don't think that this tag fits what tags are supposed to be, nor does it do what tags are supposed to do.

Should this tag be burninated? Or possibly retagged to [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic)/[logical-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-operators) depending on the case?

Comment: In the context of StackOverfow I suspect it could be made a synonym to tag "math".

Comment: Yes, it would be logical to burn [logical].

Comment: Hm. There's *logical indexing* in MATLAB. Probably not enough reason for a new `logical-indexing`-tag for questions tagged as `matlab` though.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring- Q: +78/-1, A (saying yes) +11/-1

Comment: Is it [Logical] to burninate this tag?

Comment: @Aldwoni Live long, and burninate

Comment: @Aldwoni we're in phase 2, so witty titles are punallowed.

Comment: @Aldwoni: Heh, I see I wasn't the only one to think of Mr Spock.  I was thinking "The [logical] tag is ... illogical", but I guess we need the word burninate in there somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, as Andrew mentioned, in phase 2 of the burnination process, question titles must read "Should we burninate [tag]" without a pun.

Comment: Well, this only took 3,5 years.

Comment: @Steven, 4/12 =/= 0.5

Comment: @Luuklag Yeah, but an infinite number of threes takes too long to type.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm What? When did that become policy? "Should we burninate [tag]" is so boring... :-/

Comment: @CharlesSrstka That has always been the policy. We hate fun; funny titles are allowed in phase 1 only. Oh, and in case you didn't realise, the word "burninate" is funny too. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316975/1016716

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q +156/-2, Ans saying yes +60/-1. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: What does one do for questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354826/how-to-count-number-of-true-values-in-a-logical-vector-before-false), that are about a *data type* named 'logical', and where  that is relevant to the question?  I mean, the tag [boolean] basicly covers that usage, but its name is not well matched to language-specific usage.

Comment: Is this a true or false question?

Answer (score 59):

This is an incredibly broad tag, but it looks like you've suggested a few places where it can be split. Make sure to review the questions as you are re-tagged them, as this is the best time to clean up questions that have slipped by the community.

> Should this tag be burninated?

Yes. **Let it burn!** You laid out the case pretty well in your post, I don't think I really need to explain why it should be burninated.

> Or possibly retagged to [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic)/[logical-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-operators) depending on the case?

This seems pretty reasonable for most of the questions I saw. If there are any special cases that come up that don't fit, we can figure out what other tags they can be moved to (or remove the tag completely).

Comment: Logical is too broad & "logic", "logical-operators", & code review(don't remember if that's a tag or a stack exchange but isn't really relevant) can easily replace it.

Answer (score 11):

[logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=logical),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blogical%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blogical%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blogical%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blogical%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: While working through the list of questions, I noticed quite a few using [tag:logical] for [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html). I've created a new tag for this: [tag:logical-replication]

Comment: @Michael feel free to edit the answer and add the retag guidance. It is a CW answer. We need input from everyone :-)